# WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 - maximum traffic it can hold

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-message-broker, wso2-esb

I am trying to analyse what will be the maximum traffic can wso2 ESB 5.0.0 can take or hold in a Production environment.

1. Like how many API's we can deploy in two servers in a cluster with 2 WSO2 MB?
2. What will be the maximum number of calls each API or the overall API's can take per minute?

We have 2 ESB and 2 MB servers running in a cluster. 
ESB: 16 GB RAM 100GB HD
MB: 4 GB RAm 100GB HD

Any information will be helpful.

Comment: What has ESB apis to do with MB? Anyway I suggest you to do some real load testing, even starting with the simple JMeter

Comment: Thanks. Will check on that. I was looking if someone has the numbers in the range, something like that.

Comment: you may have a look at the capacity planning of wso2 https://wso2.com/library/articles/2015/12/article-capacity-planning-exercise-with-wso2-middleware-platform/ (pre ESB/proxy). ESB itself can handle [a lot of requests](https://wso2.com/casestudies/ebay-uses-100-open-source-wso2-esb-to-process-more-than-1-billion-transactions-per-day/)